# MySQL Update query using a combination xy or yx

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I know the question is little ambiguous. I hope I am able to clarify the question here.

I have a table,[Table Name: user_group_relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdNOd.png)

```
|--------------------------------------|
| userId | userId_1 | groupId | amount |
|--------------------------------------|
|   3    |     5    |     1   |  0.00  |
|--------------------------------------|
```

I want to issue a update on the table, so as I have two columns userId and userId_1 which have the userId of two different users.

I have a relation (3,5) is there any way I can look up in the table for this combination where the relation (userId_1, userId) could have been stored as either (3,5) or (5,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
SELECT * FROM user_group_relation WHERE (userId_1 = 3 AND userId = 5) 
OR (userId_1 = 5 AND userId = 3);
```

or

```
UPDATE user_group_relation set userId_1 = <value>, userId = <value> 
WHERE (userId_1 = 3 AND userId = 5) OR (userId_1 = 5 AND userId = 3);
```

?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That was what I wish to do! Thanks for the answer!